# Having trouble understand express.js

Tags: node.js, rest, express

I am trying to learn about MEAN stack and I have followed this tutorial:

https://www.airpair.com/node.js/posts/getting-started-with-docker-for-the-nodejs-dev

The tutorial is pretty good but also basic when it comes to express.js.  One ends up with a REST API that responds with,  `<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>Express</title><link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/style.css"></head><body><h1>Express</h1><p>Welcome to Express</p></body></html>`  if I execute `curl -X GET http://172.17.0.11:3000`.  Also, if I execute: `curl -X GET http://172.17.0.11:3000/users` the API responses with `respond with a resource`.  All this was created in the tutorial when I executed: `express mynodeapp`.  I wanted to make the REST API respond to this request:

```
curl -H Content-Type: application/json -X POST -d '{username:xyz,password:xyz}' http://172.17.0.11:3000/user/add
```

So I poked around the `mynodeapp` directory and modified my `app.js` file http://pastebin.com/52TA5VZ6 . I added the stuff between the `//RED` comments.  I also added a file in the `routes` directory:

```
[root@f271de68b259 routes]# cat user.js
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* add user */
router.post('/user/add', function (req, res) {
  res.send('respond with a resource see http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.post.method');
});

module.exports = router;
```

But the response I get is:

```
<html>
<head><title>301 Moved Permanently</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>301 Moved Permanently</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title></title><link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/style.css"></head><body><h1>Not Found</h1><h2>404</h2><pre>Error: Not Found
    at app.use.res.render.message (/mynodeapp/app.js:38:13)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/mynodeapp/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (/mynodeapp/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:312:13)
    at /mynodeapp/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:280:7
    at Function.process_params (/mynodeapp/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:330:12)
    at next (/mynodeapp/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:271:10)
    at /mynodeapp/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:618:15
    at next (/mynodeapp/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:256:14)
    at Function.handle (/mynodeapp/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:176:3)
    at router (/mynodeapp/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:46:12)</pre></body></html>
```

I am kind of lost on what I am doing wrong.  Can anyone out there help me out?
Thanks!

UPDATE: Thanks for all your responses.  I have changed my `routes/user.js` to this as per your suggestions:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* add user */
router.post('/add', function (req, res) {
  res.send('respond with a resource see http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.post.method');
});

module.exports = router;
```

Now I do get the response one would expect, but I am also getting a 301 message.
Here is what `curl -H Content-Type: application/json -X POST -d '{username:xyz,password:xyz}' http://172.17.0.11:3000/user/add` is outputting now:

```
<html>
<head><title>301 Moved Permanently</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>301 Moved Permanently</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>
respond with a resource see http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.post.method
```

Is that to be expected? I am doing something else wrong now?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So in your app.js, you've defined your user route as this:

```
app.use('/user', user);
```

Then in your actual route file (user.js), you've defined the post request handler as this:

```
router.post('/user/add'
```

What this means, is that in order to get to this post request, you would need to send the request to: '/user/user/add'.

**If this is not what you want**, change:

```
router.post('/user/add'
```

to simply:

```
router.post('/add'
```

Comment: Ah! I see thanks!  I get the output I was expect plus `301 Moved Permanently` html.  Hmmm you don't happen to know what the 301 response is all about?

Comment: Your 301 response is generated by the nginx server, which could come with the Docker image. It is not related to the NodeJS server.

Comment: @RedCricket It's really not for the user, but more for search engines and caching. It's just to inform either of the two that the resource they're looking for, is accessible from another URI and hence redirects them.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to add `/user/` to your router in the code below

```
/* add user */
router.post('/user/add', function (req, res) {
  res.send('respond with a resource see http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.post.method');
});
```

Because you have specified it in `app.use('/user', user);`

Just change it to

```
/* add user */
router.post('/add', function (req, res) {
  res.send('respond with a resource see http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.post.method');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check your `app.js` generated by the express-generator. Around Line 26 it should contain something like this:

```
app.use('/users', users);
```

Which means, in your `user.js` file, the router is always used with the `/users` prefix. So you should omit the `/users` part when defining routes:

```
router.post('/add', function (req, res) {
  res.send('respond with a resource see http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.post.method');
});
```

Please note this makes your API available at `POST /users/add`, which contains an extra `s` after `user`. If you want to change this, you can always edit the `app.js` and mount the user router at `/user`:

```
app.use('/user', users);
```

Please check the [Express Router docs](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#router) to see how to define routes under a router, and how to mount them under a URL prefix.